# Uninitialized constant error in controller when deploy to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I try to set up devise and omniauth by follow https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview and deploy to heroku. There is no error in localhost , but when I push to heroku , the app crash. In heroku logs , i found the 'uninitialized constant Users' error in omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb . How do I initialize the Users? I have heroku rake db:migrate already. But I cant run heroku console because app crash , so i cant check is there a User model. 
For your information , I generate the controller by `rails g omniauth_callbacks_controller`

In `heroku logs`

```
/disk1/home/slugs/338566_ad6243a_bbb1-19eae435-d901-44ba-9dd5-baf36d656448/mnt/app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:1: uninitialized constant Users (NameError)
```

In omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure your model User is commit and push ?

Comment: In localhost when i 'rails c' and type irb(main):001:0> User
=> User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, password_salt: string, reset_password_token: string, remember_token: string, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

Comment: So i think it is committed and when i git push heroku master , it says up to date , I do git add . and git commit -m "wateva"

Comment: I think the problem is at Users::OmniauthCallbacksController because the heroku logs mention /omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the User model has been created in Heroku's database?

In your terminal (NOT the rails console!) enter

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

That will migrate Heroku's DB's to match your code. Do you then still have the error?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku needs to migrate with model, so you need to run

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

then refresh your page, now its working :)